# Sync SharePoint contact list to all Exchange users personal contact list

Tags: exchange, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have users who have centralised their contacts in a SharePoint list.

They would like to access this list on their phones, synchronised over ActiveSync.

Is there any way to l sync from a SharePoint list to an Exchange user’s personal contact list?

If not, then an option to use Exchange public folder is OK (although I don’t know how one would do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could sync contacts with MS outlook
then use folder sync plug in from CodeTwo
http://www.codetwo.com/freeware/foldersync-addin/

then sync sherpoint contacts with primary contact folder in outlook (the one sync with exchange)

its the only manual trick I found

Answer (score 0):

Currently Microsoft doesn't support any feasible way for you to sync SharePoint contact list to mobile phones.

The best 3rd party solution we found for syncing shared contact list to phones (Android) is "Contact Sync for SharePoint" by Rubik's Solution:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rubikssolutions.sharepointconnector&hl=en

It works with SharePoint 2013 and Office 365 (but not with SharePoint 2010).